AWS ECS - слишком медленный ответ на эластичный контейнерный сервис
У меня есть проблема на ЭКС (эластичный контейнерный сервис ), я использую это сервис чтобы развернуть фронтэнд приложение, которое было сделано с использованием Angular и Angular SSR (рендеринг на стороне сервера)
Я развернул это приложение, но когда я подключаюсь из веб-браузера, приходится ждать 5-7 секунд чтобы страница загрузилась, эта моя проблема.
Я уже пробовал запустить это приложение на localhost, но ответ очень быстрый там, поэтому я думаю, что это проблема с ЭКС конфигирации.
Не совсем понимаю, что делать теперь.
Дайте знать, если нужно добавить в вопрос какую-то дополнительную информацию.

Кажется, файлы использовались из папки которые стоят на ЭКС, поэтому было так медленно.
Я скопировал все файлы на S3, и всё заработало как надо.
